# compile single.. modified file for opencv python

Tags: linux, opencv, makefile

I'm currently trying to expose different internal c++ function to python,
for example, to expose the elbp function, I opened the [facerec.hpp](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib/blob/master/modules/face/include/opencv2/face/facerec.hpp) and put the following code

```
CV_EXPORTS_W Mat elbp(InputArray src, int radius, int neighbors);
```

after namespace while removing the static before the wrapper function:

```
static Mat elbp(InputArray src, int radius, int neighbors) {
Mat dst;
elbp(src, dst, radius, neighbors);
return dst;}
```

After this, what I did was to run the cmake in the opencv build directory
and then make the whole opencv again,the whole process took like 2 hour(since im doing it on a raspberry pi) which is really painful.
I dont want to switch to c++ atm, is there any other way to simply expose the internal c++ function(or do some modification on the existing function) without recompile the whole opencv?

I'm quite new to both Linux and opencv，i would be really appreciated if anyone can help.....

Comment: Was this the first time you built opencv in that directory? You shouldn't need to rebuild *everything* for any given change. Only things that are directly affected by that change. (For a header file that might be a lot of things though.) That said you could look into cross-compiling instead.

Comment: @Etan Reisner Thx  for responding, no I built the opencv in that direc before, What I did was deleting it after running the make install(mainly to reduce the size of the file ),I suppose what I should do is keeping the file under that build directory?Assuming I changed a line within a internal function definiation,nothing else was done, then what should I do to make the changes applied to whole opencv?Sorry for asking such basic questions, but atm I have absolutely no idea how the compile working under Linux

Comment: Also I looked up cross-compiling, I noticed its a way creating  executable code for different platform?Sorry but I cant see how it is related to the question

Comment: Yes, deleting things means they need to be rebuilt. But rebuilding just the binary/library shouldn't have been that intensive I wouldn't think (but who knows). Keeping everything you can around if you need to build again will make subsequent builds faster. And cross-compiling is relevant because if you use a system where compiling *doesn't* take two hours then this question is less relevant since the main impetus (that being that it takes too long to compile) goes away.

Comment: Thanks,what I really need at the moment is to have a step by step tutorial about how to rebuild the library after minor changes in a wuick way, but I guess that would make me to lazy ....;(, I will look into that

Comment: You just rerun make. If the build system is at all sane and you haven't deleted anything then only the bits that need to be rebuilt will build and it will be as fast as that is doable. If that's too long (because you are modifying core header files, etc.) then you get to look at building somewhere faster.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will try that out!